# Is there anyway to run File History not to backup locally on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, file-history

We have Windows 8.1 laptop that have the File history is being setup into a network backup drive. It's working ok BUT due to the machine is not always at the premise so the user can take this home and obviously when the the machine can't see the network shared backup drive and it's backup to local drive.

My questions are:

1. Is there anyway to stop this (backing into local drive) if the machine can't see the network backup drive?
2. This machine has SDXC slot. Can we force to backup to this slot if the machine can't see the network shared backup drive  (instead of using local drive)?

Thanks

Comment: Please add more info about how you are doing the backup.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select any drive for using as a backup for File History. The instructions for doing that are here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/set-drive-file-history